# XML Python find all paragraphs and extract text doesn't find ALL paragraphs

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml

I want to find all paragraphs, and it seems like it works, but I'm not sure every paragraph is taken. For example in this piece of XML:

```
<body>
    <sec id="s1">
      <title>Introduction</title>
      <p>Ordered segregation of the genome during cell division requires bipolar attachment to spindle microtubules [<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="pbio-0060207-b001">1</xref>] and maintenance of sister chromatid cohesion until anaphase onset [<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="pbio-0060207-b002">2</xref>]. Cohesin provides a physical link between sister chromatids, and cleavage of cohesin subunits results from separase activation after the spindle
</p> </sec></body>
```

The code to extract it is:

```
for nameoffile in os.listdir(words_input_dir):
  if filename.endswith(".xml"):
      tree = ET.parse(filename)
      root = tree.getroot()
      node = root.findall("./body/sec/p")
      for x in node:
        print(x.text)
```

But it seems like it doesn't get ALL paragraphs. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I say if x.text=None print "None", sometimes it doesn't find the text even if it's there

Comment: So show a *specific* example where that happens.

Answer (score 0):

I think you find all `<p>` with your code, but what you maybe miss is the `tail` content of some `</closing tag>`. I will use the xml.etree.ElementTree to explain your code. On the other hand I recommend you for parse `html` use the **Beautiful Soup** ([bs4](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)) will be the better solution, but you have to install it via `pip install beautifulsoup4`.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd

tree = ET.parse("html.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

columns = ["TAG", "ATTRIBUTE", "TEXT", "TAIL"]
data = []
for elem in root.iter():
    #print(elem.tag, elem.attrib, elem.text, elem.tail)
    all = elem.tag, elem.attrib, elem.text, elem.tail
    data.append(all)
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
df.to_csv('out_html.csv')
```

Output, opend in LibreOffice:
[image]